# XXXX (Class Name) does not implement inherited abstract member 'SecurityToken.SecurityKeys.get''

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0

> XXXX (Class Name) does not implement inherited abstract member
> 'SecurityToken.SecurityKeys.get'

Tried implemented override method. But still throws error

Comment: Could you share some code so we can see what you've tried?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.